# How to convert a TAR file into an ISO file

Tags: linux, tar, iso, convert, disk-image

I have a Linux TAR file that I would like to convert directly into an ISO.  Is there a way to do this, preferably, without having to extract the contents of the file first?

This would be similar to the [following question](https://superuser.com/questions/89826/good-open-source-free-program-to-convert-a-bz2-file-to-iso); however, this is focused on plain or straight-up tar files and not related to bzip or a bzipped tar.

This is also something that I intended to use within a script and the reason that I do not want to extract it first.

Comment: Theoretically it could be done without having to extract each of the files *to disk* (they have to be extracted from the archive in order to be put into the new image), but I don't know of anything that does.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without extracting the tar?

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to pipe it to something like stdin and then pipe it on over to the iso file ???

Comment: I am not sure if this would work or not, since I am not 100% for sure what the command is doing. -- tar -jxf /dev/stdin file.tar | mkisofs -o file.iso -stream-media-size 512

Comment: The -stream-media-size option was actually made for this! :-) See [the genisoimage man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/genisoimage) for info -- currently it mentions tar in the docs for this option (and uses it in the examples for it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) to access the contents of the tar archive as if it was a directory. AVFS is a virtual filesystem built on [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). Point your favorite ISO builder to the directory inside the tar archive.

```
mountavfs
cd ~/.avfs/path/to/archive.tar\#
genisoimage -o /path/to/iso .
```

Comment: @ Gilles - thanks for the idea.  This looks like it might be an excellent idea; however, I am on CentOS 6 and am running into problems trying to get AVFS installed.

Answer (score 2):

If your primary objectives are to expedite the process and to avoid unnecessary disk activity for performance reasons, *and* you have plenty of RAM to spare relative to the size of your tarball, you can extract the .tar into RAM using [tmpfs](http://rhkernel.org/#RHEL6+2.6.32-19.el6/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt). This option is very likely the fastest available, unless you're able to get @bulleric's pipe approach to work *and* you're reading from one disk and writing to another.

Answer (score 2):

```
archivemount /file.tar /media/ISO
```

or *uncompressed .tar* and

```
genisoimage -o myfile.iso directory_src
```

(*can be folder* `/media/ISO` *or point mount* `/media/cdrom`)

Answer (score -2):

You must extract it but you dont must extract it to your harddrive
you can use stdtout  and pipe it to genisoimage or mkisofs

`tar --to-stdout xf tareddata.tar | genisoimage -o image.iso  tareddata`

test it:
`mount -o loop image.iso /mnt`

you can write a small script to automize this issue

greez bull

Comment: And how would it tell one file from the next?

Comment: When I run this I get a series of errors, the first is: tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options.  The next error is:  I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings).  The last error is:  genisoimage: No such file or directory. Invalid node - 'tareddata'.

Comment: the first problem i solvet  i have take a wrong option in tar ;  the 2nd one hmm in my opinion the first directory get extractet the same name as the  as the unextracted directory like tardata.tar tardata

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly sure there's no way this can work; -1 .